# localhost: I want my .php to access a folder in another drive

Tags: php, apache, alias

localhost: I want my .php to access a folder in another drive.

At first I thought it could be done with Apache Alias, but now I don't know.

`D:/Appserv/www/x/y/file.php`

I want that .php to read the contents of:

`E:/foldie/`

Comment: Can you please tell us what you've done to try, and how it's failed?

Comment: Show us some code. It's hard to guess your problem.

Comment: `$a = new DirectoryIterator('E:/foldie');` doesn't work?

Comment: I need my php's to be able to access a folder outside the documentRoot. I don't know how.

Comment: PHP couldn't care less about the document root. That only affects files you access from outside with a web browser.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the [syntax of the Alias directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/mod/mod_alias.html#alias) is quite straightforward:

```
Description: Maps URLs to filesystem locations
Syntax:      Alias URL-path file-path|directory-path
Context:     server config, virtual host
Status:      Base
Module:      mod_alias
```

... and the included example clarifies the rest:

```
Alias /image /ftp/pub/image
```

The fact that you've tagged this as `PHP` suggests that you are either trying to set `Alias` inside an `.htaccess` file (which is simply not allowed, it needs to go in the main server config) or misinterpreting the directive as having something to do with file system symlinks (which is not, it only affect HTTP requests).

Just type the full path (with drive letter and all) in whatever PHP function you are trying to use and, if you use back slashes, make sure you double them:

```
foreach( glob('E:/foldie/*') as $item ){
}
foreach( glob('E:\\foldie\\*') as $item ){
}
```

Comment: `print_r(glob("E:/foldie/"));` prints an empty array. But foldie has files inside. This isn't working. Also, I don't know how/where to add the alias bit.

Comment: My examples with `glob()` are wrong (I'll fix them now) but your empty array suggests there was an error: the PHP user does not have permission for the folder, or the drive letter is a network drive not defined for such user. Care to explain why you need an alias?

Comment: I need my php's to access files outside the documentRoot. Those files happen to be on a different drive altogether.

Comment: What makes you think that PHP cannot read files outside the document root? Why is having a different drive such a big issue? You should edit the question and add your real code.

Comment: $dir=opendir(glob("E:/foldie/"));  
$dir=opendir("E:/foldie/");  
$dir=dirname("E:/foldie");  
$dir=realpath("E:/foldie");  

Nothing seems to work. I realize I'm not being clear but I'm just a beginner in all this.

Comment: Please edit the original question, code in comments in unreadable. Read the manual for the functions you are trying to use: opendir() expects a string with a path, not an array, and so on. You don't have to guess!